# How to get extracted image in listview with c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have extracted icon from an application but how can i show it in the listview

```
Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Photoshop.exe");
```

I have the icon in the variable in icon but i want to show it in listview is there any way? Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably just convert your `Icon` into an `Image` via the [`Icon.ToBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method (since [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) derives from [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)). Then just create a [`PictureBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx) control containing your image and add it to your `ListView.Controls` collection as seen below :

```
// Get your image
var image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Program Files\Photoshop.exe").ToBitmap();
// Create a picture box to display in your ListView
var picture = new PictureBox()
{
    Image = image,
    Height = image.Height,
    Width = image.Width
};
// Add this to your ListView
YourListView.Controls.Add(picture);
```

Comment: It helps me a lot but there is a problem i want it to the row i mean to add this as an item

Comment: is there any way to add this in the item?

Comment: Most Web Forms Controls function as containers (and can hold additional `Control` objects). It's likely that you could iterate through each of your Items within your ListView and add this `PictureBox` to each of the inner items themselves. It's been a *long* time since I have worked with Windows Forms, but I would think that would be doable.